# Image auto load from desktop (AS3)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I need to load an external image into the clip from the desktop using:

> ```
> var myimage:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath
> ```

Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var imageClip:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var imageLoader:Loader = new Loader();

function loadImage():void
{
    var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath( "Your Image Path" );
    imageLoader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, handleImageLoad );
    imageLoader.load( new URLRequest(file.url) );
}

function handleImageLoad( e:Event ):void
{
    trace('Complete')
    imageClip.addChild( imageLoader );
}

loadImage();
```